# Typecasting of inherited structure gives g++ compliation error

Tags: c++, structure

I have the following code to print the derived structure variable in a global function. But when I tried to compile the code, g++ returns the following error. Is it not possible to typecast the structure to a derived class from base class which is passed to the function by pass by value?

```
In function 'void print(B)':
Line 19: error: no matching function for call to 'D1::D1(B&)'
```

Code:

```
struct B{
    int a;
    B()
    {
        a = 0;
    }
};

struct D1:public B{
    std::string s1;
    D1()
    {
        s1.assign("test");
    }
};

void print(B ib)
{
    cout << static_cast<D1>(ib).s1<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    D1 d1;
    cout << d1.s1 <<endl;
    print(d1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uh-oh, what a rubbish code... ever heard of *constructor initializer list*?

Comment: @Griwes: I know about constructor initializer list. I copied the code which I tried in my machine. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void print(B ib)

D1 d1;
print(d1);
```

Your object is truncated to `B` in `print` function. You should use `reference` or `pointer` instead of value.

```
cout << static_cast<D1>(ib).s1<<endl;
```

Use `static_cast<D1&>(ib).s1`. In both cases `ib` should be reference!

Comment: Indeed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: `dynamic_cast` only works for polymorphic types. It's much better to change the argument type to `D1` (perhaps with a `const` and/or a `&`) if that's what the function requires.

Comment: @BoBTFish:Link explained me the slicing problem. Thanks alot